# Form.Dropdown semantic ui- show incomplete fields as red with error message

Tags: javascript, validation, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

#### Expected Result:

I currently have 3 Form.Dropdown fields which are required fields. If the user presses "next" without making a selection in those 3 fields, I would like the dropdowns to turn red and display one error message as to what they need to do to correct the issue.

#### Actual Result:

I am not sure how to do the form validation, so right now the boxes are permanently red and the error message is always there.

The dropdown field:

```
<Form.Dropdown
  defaultValue={this.state.initial}
  inline
  //control={Dropdown}
  label='Home'
  selection
  className="dropdown2"
  name='home'
  value={home}
  error
  required 
/>
```

Next button:

```
<Button
  color = "green"
  type="submit"
  className="nextbuttonuser"
  onClick={this.handleClick}
  onSubmit={this.handle} 
>
  Next   
  <i class="right arrow icon"></i>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do something like this...

Inside handleClick function check if value of dropdown is ok. If not, set somewhere in state that that dropdown should have error

```
<Form.Dropdown
  defaultValue={this.state.initial}
  inline
  //control={Dropdown}
  label='Home'
  selection
  className="dropdown2"
  name='home'
  value={home}
  error={this.checkDropdownValue}
  required 
/>


checkDropdownValue = () => {
  if(this.state.home === '') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

or something similar to this